# MOSTRAR DATOS EN UN INPUT TEXT

Tags: php, mysql, select, entrada

Tengo el código para realizar un SELECT con PHP; Pero quiero saber el codigo para que a partir de una opcion del SELECT que yo escoja me muestre los datos en un INPUT TEXT.

ESTE ES EL CODIGO QUE HE REALIZADO:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" name="basic_validate" id="basic_validate" novalidate>
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Seleccione el nombre de la parroquia:</label>
         <div class="controls">
        <select name="cbx_parroquia" id="cbx_parroquia" class="span9 m-wrap">
              <option value="0">Seleccionar Parroquia</option>
               <?php 
                 $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'admin', 'UGTESPE2019', 'georreferenciacion');
                  $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM parroquia");
                  while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
                  {
                    echo '<option value="'.$valores[codigo_parroquia].'">'.$valores[nombre_parroquia].'</option>';
                  }
                ?>
        </select>
        </div>
          </div>
             <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">El código de la parroquia es: </label>
            <div class="controls">
                 <?php 
                 $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'admin', 'UGTESPE2019', 'georreferenciacion');
                 $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT*FROM parroquia");
                 echo '<input type="text" name="codigo_parroquia2" id="codigo_parroquia2" value="'.$valores[codigo_parroquia].'" class="span9 m-wrap">';
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: Y ESTE ME GUSTARIA QUE FUERA EL RESULTADO]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo debes utilizar el evento "**change**" de tu **select** para enviar el valor al **input**. Te dejo un ejemplo sencillo de como hacerlo. Vamos a indicarle a nuestro select que en el evento "change" va a llamar a la función `mostrarResultado()` y le va a pasar como **parámetro** el valor actual del **select** (valor seleccionado). Luego en nuestra función vamos a seleccionar por **ID** nuestro **input** y le vamos a asignar el valor.

```js
function mostrarResultado(value){
if(value !== "Seleccionar...")
  document.getElementById("txtResult").value= value;
else
 document.getElementById("txtResult").value= '';
}
```

```html
<p>Seleccionar un valor</p>
<select onchange="mostrarResultado(this.value)">
<option >Seleccionar...</option>
<option value"uno">Opcíon 1</option>
<option value"dos">Opcíon 2</option>
<option value"tres">Opcíon 3</option>
</select>
<p>Valor seleccionado:</p>
<input type="text" id="txtResult">
```

Comment: Gracias @Fran Islas me salio el resultado esperado; cualquier inquietud seguiere haciendo preguntas

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un código que te podría funcionar, pero debes tener en cuenta algunas cosas:

1. En la etiqueta `<form>` te he puesto un `action="index.php"`, pero debes poner el nombre de tu fichero si es que no se llama así
2. El `isset($_POST["cbx_parroquia"])` comprueba que al pulsar en el botón enviar del formulario, cuando recarga la página del `action` exista un valor llamado `cbx_parroquia`, que debería existir ya que así se llama tu `<select>`
3. Te he puesto un `if`que comprueba si existe `cbx_parroquia` y si existe, te lo auto selecciona en el `<select>`

Si no funciona algo es por tema de las comillas en los `echo`, que tienes mucho lío por ahí

```html
<form action="index.php" class="form-horizontal" method="post" name="basic_validate" id="basic_validate" novalidate>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Seleccione el nombre de la parroquia:</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <select name="cbx_parroquia" id="cbx_parroquia" class="span9 m-wrap">
        <option value="0">Seleccionar Parroquia</option>
        <?php 
          $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'admin', 'UGTESPE2019', 'georreferenciacion');
          $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM parroquia");
            while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
              if(isset($_POST["cbx_parroquia"]) && $_POST["cbx_parroquia"] == $valores[codigo_parroquia]) {
                echo '<option value="'.$valores[codigo_parroquia].'" selected="selected">'.$valores[nombre_parroquia].'</option>';
              } else {
               echo '<option value="'.$valores[codigo_parroquia].'">'.$valores[nombre_parroquia].'</option>';
              }
            }
         ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">El código de la parroquia es: </label>
    <div class="controls">
      <?php 
       if(isset($_POST["cbx_parroquia"])) {
         echo '<input type="text" name="codigo_parroquia2" id="codigo_parroquia2" value="'.$_POST["cbx_parroquia"].'" class="span9 m-wrap">';
     }else{
      echo '<input type="text" name="codigo_parroquia2" id="codigo_parroquia2" value="" class="span9 m-wrap">';
     }
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```