# Cómo extraer el contenido de un select y pasarlo a un input (el contenido, NO EL VALOR)

Tags: php

necesito extraer de un select el contenido, y pasarlo a un input text algo asi:

```
<select name="idModalidadTitulacion" id_modalidad onChange="this.form['modalidadTitulacion'].value=this.value" required>
            <option value="">Selecciona una opcion de modalidad de titulacion</option>
            <option value="1">POR TESIS</option>
            <option value="2">POR PROMEDIO</option>
            <option value="3">POR ESTUDIOS DE POSGRADOS</option>
            <option value="4">POR EXPERIENCIA LABORAL</option>
            <option value="5">POR CENEVAL</option>
            <option value="6">OTRO</option>
        </select><br>
<input type="text" name="modalidadTitulacion" placeholder="Modalidad" required readonly><br>
```

Entonces el valor del idModalidad sea 1-6 y que el valor del modalidadTitulacion sea (POR TESIS, POR PROMEDIO ETC.)

Estoy aprendiendo, o si hay alguna alternativa les agradezco

Comment: Podrías utilizar javascript como [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/233477/65107)

Comment: al extraerlo en una variable con post me sigue jalando el valor osea si selecciono del select "POR TESIS" al llamar el valor de variable por post me arroja "1", porque? o esta mal estructurado? gracias @RafaelBautistaMartinez

Comment: No está mal, sino que funciona así, cuando posteas un formulario en el caso de los `select` lo que se manda es el `value`. Si quieres mandar otro dato tendrás que añadirlo aparte al hacer el POST. Aunque no entiendo bien por qué quieres mandar el texto ¿? Si estás usando una tabla por ejemplo lo más interesante sería usar los ID numéricos y en otros casos, es mejor tener en el servidor un array asociativo desde el cual sacar el dato en base a un índice numérico.

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo lo que quieres hacer es no obtener el VALOR sino el texto de dentro de la etiqueta OPTION.

Para ello te puede valer el atributo innerHTML.

```js
(function(){
 document.querySelector('#idModalidadTitulacion').onchange = function(){
   var seleccionado = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    document.getElementById('modalidadTitulacion').value = seleccionado.innerHTML;
  }
})();
```

```html
<select name="idModalidadTitulacion" id="idModalidadTitulacion" required>
            <option value="">Selecciona una opcion de modalidad de titulacion</option>
            <option value="1">POR TESIS</option>
            <option value="2">POR PROMEDIO</option>
            <option value="3">POR ESTUDIOS DE POSGRADOS</option>
            <option value="4">POR EXPERIENCIA LABORAL</option>
            <option value="5">POR CENEVAL</option>
            <option value="6">OTRO</option>
        </select><br>
<input type="text" name="modalidadTitulacion" id="modalidadTitulacion" placeholder="Modalidad" required readonly><br>
```

Comment: gracias bro, si genera en el input el texto y no el valor pero como dice A. Cedano, en mi base de datos me sigue jalando el valor osea 1-6, y no el contenido entonces intentare con arrays asociativos, creo que seria una posible solucion asi que estoy investigando esa parte si esq no hay de otra, como decia soy novatito y voy despacio gracias por aportar